# SharePoint 2013 and Office Web Apps - Unable to view documents after successful set up and config

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-web-apps, owa

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219455(v=office.15).aspx
We have followed the TechNet article carefully and we have been successful, however, Office documents do not open in OWA.

I get the error "sorry we couldn't open this presentation because we run into a problem, please try again", same with Word, slightly different with Excel.

Our server names are set as External-https. Our SP configuration part has been exactly like described by the TechNet article. The binding is successful (and it does say external-https) and the SPWOPI has been changed to external-https.

We run out of ideas. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

This behavior could be caused if you have your Alternative Access Mapping (AAM) Default Zone set to use protocol http while your OWA is set to use HTTPS. One solution I found is to change the Default Zone to use HTTPS.

Change the Default Zone by going to `Central Administration > Application Management > Configure Alternative Access Mapping > MyWebApp > Edit Internal URLs` and set protocol to HTTPS.

[image]

Reference: [SharePoint 2013 Office Web Apps Problem - Unable to Open/View/Edit](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f7be5f88-8c98-464e-8596-60956b5e98fd/sharepoint-2013-office-web-apps-problem-unable-to-openviewedit?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but when I get to my web app, I do not see Edit Internal URL but EDIT PUBLIC URL, then I have ADD INTERNAL URL, is this normal? As far as I understood this 'intranet' was made to be available to the company users when logged in from external computers.

Comment: @susan Strange I think. You have five zones where one is Public, which should be used for external web sites. But is it a public facing web site you have?

Comment: no, it is internal but accessible from the internet (ie: working from home). The system was set up by a SP agency, most of the time taking decisions out of their own will without consulting with IT people here and to be honest, this is not the first thing they have not done properly or traditionally. So what should I do to correct this and eventually correct also my Office Web Apps problem?

Comment: @susan Check the healh analyzer report and see if anything looks suspicious. Found in Central Administration > Monitoring > Review problems and solutions. I havn't heard of the tool SP Agency before. The one I use when installing a farm is http://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/ which I know work well when you configure Office Web Apps as well. Is this a production environment, or a test environment?

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, I meant that SharePoint was set up by an external agency (SharePoint consultants) and they took a lot of decisions that I find questionable. I do believe they have used an autoinstaller, because I saw a file on the server. Is the health check you are suggesting about the error I get when I open a document with OWA or a general check? this is prod, we only have prod. IT team is small, company is small, no need for a test env for now.

Comment: @susan Ah I see :-) You could monitor the ULS Log, but it is a teadious job, and someone with .NET experience may need to read out what could be wrong. Check the time when you try to access a document with OWA and find the time in your ULS log. You find the logs here: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS

Comment: I am not sure which line hosts the error, I have noticed at least 20+lines related to my event

Comment: I sent you an email at your gmail address, the log was too long to post it here

Answer (score 1):

Before few days I was having same issue. Office web app was install correctly and every thing was done correctly. But still when I was trying preview any file I was getting error "**Sorry we couldn't open this ...**"

Then I start digging ULS logs and I found SPWOPI is failing due to net tcp. So I did steps as below

1. My first step was go on the both the server's services  and check net tcp is running or not. But I found net tcp service was missing.
2. Then I go to Windows features and Install HTTP activation and Non-HTTP activation. You can add both for .Net 3.5.1 and 4.0

You can follow this http://rohitguptablog.wordpress.com/tag/net-tcp/

Hope this can help you to solve the issue

Comment: This actually just got my OWA implementation up and running, thank you.

Comment: 1. I have checked both and tcp is up and running on both and 2. HTTP activation and non-HTTP activation are installed. I have tried to follow the steps in the link you have provided up to step 3, since I do not have visual studio and I wouldn't know how to proceed further

Comment: no need of Visual Studio. If those service are running than you are good to go. Kindly can you post your ULS logs over here

Comment: apologies for my ignorance, do I take the ULS logs in the SP server or OWA server?

Comment: SP Server u can use ULS log viewer than open the current ULS Log. Then try to browse any Web App file. You will get error in ULS. Kindly just past that error over here

Comment: I have the logs on a word document but they are too long to copy paste here. How can I give them to you?

Comment: send me on dropbox or google drive or sky drive link to my email id milindsaraswala@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons why you might be getting this issue , Make sure the owa is on the different server and properly joined to the sharepoint server . Create the owa farm and make sure the sharepoint server is in healthy state .

**I encountered this issue and i could observe that there was a security windows patch was being done on our servers which caused the issue , i had to unjoin the Owa server from the farm ,uninstall the owa server and install again .**

IMPORTANT:

http://www.wictorwilen.se/office-web-apps-2013-patching-your-wac-farm-with-no-downtime
http://www.wictorwilen.se/Tags/Office%20Web%20Apps

PS: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f7be5f88-8c98-464e-8596-60956b5e98fd/sharepoint-2013-office-web-apps-problem-unable-to-openviewedit?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: can you specify which security patch? is the KB mentioned in the TechNet article? if so we have installed prior as instructed.

Comment: Any patches which you do on server without taking out of farm will break . Not sure of the patch ,because there were lot of patches being done . Request you to follow the links i provided for finding potential issue , like i said there might several reasons you might be face these issues .